# Get specific columns of table in hibernate using addEntity

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am familiar with Java but really new with ORM and Hibernate.

I am using the following query to get the resultset of all columns of a table in hibernate.

```
(List<Neighborhood>)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Neighborhood").addEntity(Neighborhood.class).list();
```

I want to get only two specific column from this table. I looked up over the internet but not able to find the solution which can be used as a modification of above statement.

I tried the below query but getting - `SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet`

```
(List<Neighborhood>)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT neighborhoodName,educationYouth FROM Neighborhood").addEntity(Neighborhood.class).list();
```

Edit:

Two more attempted queries after @scaryWombat's suggestion. Both give the same exception

First

```
List list = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT neighborhoodName,educationYouth FROM Neighborhood").list();
```

Second

```
String sql = "SELECT neighborhoodName,educationYouth FROM Neighborhood";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
List results = query.list();
```

Edit2:

After @Tehmina's solution, I am getting one error - `java.sql.SQLException: Column 'educationYouth' not found`  because educationYouth is an object of class name "EducationYouth". 
In the Neighborhood table there is no column with name educationYouth but all the column from EducationYouth class.

Comment: do not try to use the `Neighborhood` class as the enitity

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm

Comment: No, it does not work. I get the same exception.

Comment: Please show your modified code.

Comment: Are you columns names correct? maybe `neighborhood_name` ?

Comment: Column names are correct. I added one more edit please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
(List<Neighborhood>)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Neighborhood").list();
```

To avoid the overhead of using ResultSetMetadata, or simply to be more explicit in what is returned, one can use addScalar():

```
(List<Neighborhood>)session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Neighborhood").addScalar("neighborhoodName", Hibernate.STRING).addScalar("educationYouth", Hibernate.STRING);
```

Or try this
Hibernate automatically converts the data into appropriate type. The automatic conversion does not work in all cases and in that case we have an overloaded version of addScalar():

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Neighborhood");        
    q.addScalar("neighborhoodName");    
    q.addScalar("educationYouth");   
     List<Object[]> rows = q.list();
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    System.out.println(row[0] + " " + row[1] );
```

Don't forget to check in the hibernate config file

```
<!--hibernate.cfg.xml -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

I hope it would resolve your error.

Comment: Hi @Tehmina, thank you I think your second solution will work. I am actually getting an error but it is because I have incomplete information in question. Actually "educationYouth" is a seperate class. Class name is "EducationYouth". Do you know what modification will be required in that case?

Comment: Welcome @denis , simply remove all after  q.addScalar("neighborhoodName");  and add the following code        
    List<String> names = q.list();
    System.out.println(names);